# requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground internal server error

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have implemented the `requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground` code to my app (xcode 7 using swift) for a login-screen. I used several tutorials, but I'm having the following error:

> "Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.12.0).

I'm wondering if more people have seen this problem, because the site of Parse states that this is a problem we can't solve.

Thanks.

Comment: What service are you using? (Parse, Firebase, etc.)

Comment: I'm using Parse with the Heroku server

Comment: Check out my answer @SvenCozijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available on Parse Server. The team is working on implementing it but has not given a timeframe (yet) on a release. I you have an app in production and really want to get a mail service out now, check out services, like [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/). I expect that, when the Parse team adds the mail service, it will be a lot better than what was offered on the "old Parse."